# Proving a inequality applying Chebyshev's sum inequality

Tags: inequality, contest-math

> Prove that $$\forall
> > x,y,z>0,~\sum_\text{cyc}\frac{2^x}{2^x-1}\ge\Big(1+\frac{1}{3}\sum_\text{cyc}2^{-x}\Big)\Big(\sum_\text{cyc}\frac{2^{x+y}}{2^{x+y}-1}\Big)$$

First of all, for the sake of simplicity I made the notations $a=2^x,b=2^y,c=2^z$.

I thought it's better to start from the RHS and somehow get to the LHS. Opening the brackets is probably a dead end, but we can use Chebyshev's inequality to have things more organized.

Assuming WLOG
$$a\le b\le c$$
and applying Chebyshev's inequality for the ordered triplets
$$\big(1+\frac{1}{a},1+\frac{1}{b},1+\frac{1}{c}\big),~\big(\frac{ab}{ab-1},\frac{bc}{bc-1},\frac{ca}{ca-1}\big)$$
can be proved using the monotonicity of the function $\frac{x}{x-1},~x\in(1,\infty)$ -- we get that
$$\text{RHS}\le\Big(1+\frac{1}{a}\Big)\frac{ab}{ab-1}+\Big(1+\frac{1}{b}\Big)\frac{ac}{ac-1}+\Big(1+\frac{1}{c}\Big)\frac{bc}{bc-1}$$

I made a 3D graph of the last function in GeoGebra (I fixed one of the variables) and it seems like it is below our original LHS for $a,b,c\in(1,\infty)$, but how can we prove it? I think I am on the right track, but I don't know how to continue. Any hints / help are appreciated.

EDIT: I'm not 100% sure it works for any $a,b,c$, to prove it one might have to use that $b\in[a,c]$, because I applied Chebyshev's inequality under this condition.

Comment: Are you sure $$\text{RHS}\le\Big(1+\frac{1}{a}\Big)\frac{ab}{ab-1}+\Big(1+\frac{1}{b}\Big)\frac{ac}{ac-1}+\Big(1+\frac{1}{c}\Big)\frac{bc}{bc-1}$$ is correct?

By symmetry I would expect

$$\text{RHS}\le\Big(1+\frac{1}{a}\Big)\frac{ab}{ab-1}+\Big(1+\frac{1}{b}\Big)\frac{bc}{bc-1}+\Big(1+\frac{1}{c}\Big)\frac{ca}{ca-1}$$ or similar.

Comment: @AlDante Note that there's the assumption of $  a \leq b \leq c$, so there isn't your "By symmetry". $\quad$ OP explained how they were pairing up the monotonic sequences.

Comment: @CalvinLin Thank you.

Comment: @CalvinLin 
$$\Big(1+\frac{1}{3}\sum_\text{cyc}2^{-x}\Big)\Big(\sum_\text{cyc}\frac{2^{x+y}}{2^{x+y}-1}\Big) = $$ 

$$\Big(\sum_\text{cyc}\frac{2^{x+y}}{2^{x+y}-1}\Big) + \frac{1}{3}\Big(\sum_\text{cyc}2^{-x}\sum_\text{cyc}\frac{2^{x+y}}{2^{x+y}-1}\Big) \le $$ 

$$\Big(\sum_\text{cyc}\frac{2^{x+y}}{2^{x+y}-1}\Big) + \frac{1}{3}\sum_\text{cyc}\Big(2^{-x}\frac{2^{x+y}}{2^{x+y}-1}\Big) \text{ by Chebyshev's sum inequality}$$ 

$$=\sum_\text{cyc}\frac{2^{x+y}}{2^{x+y}-1} + \frac{1}{3}\sum_\text{cyc}\frac{2^y}{2^{x+y}-1}$$

Comment: Making the substitution $=2^,=2^,=2^z$:
$$=\sum_\text{cyc}\frac{ab}{ab-1} + \frac{1}{3}\sum_\text{cyc}\frac{b}{ab-1} = $$

$$=\sum_\text{cyc}\Big(1 + \frac{1}{3a}\Big)\frac{ab}{ab-1}$$

I was referring to cyclic symmetry.